# HttpUrlConnection POST request throwing FileNotFound exception, how to resolve this error?

Tags: android

HttpUrlConnection throwing FileNotFound exception, where json object is passed in DataOutputStream. How to resolve this issue?
Why it throwing FileNotFound exception?

```
public final String apiCall(String pUrl,JSONObject jsonObject) {

    try {

        URL url = new URL(pUrl);
        HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();


        httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        httpURLConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
        httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
        httpURLConnection.connect();

        DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(httpURLConnection.getOutputStream());
        wr.writeBytes(jsonObject.toString());
        wr.flush();
        wr.close();

        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(httpURLConnection.getInputStream()));
        try{
            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            String line;

            while((line = bufferedReader.readLine())!= null) {
                stringBuilder.append(line);
            }

            return stringBuilder.toString();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            return "ERROR";
        } finally{
            bufferedReader.close();
            httpURLConnection.disconnect();
        }
    }catch (Exception e) {
        return "ERROR";
    }
}
```

Comment: What line throws this error? Post your full logcat

Comment: last catch throwing exception

Comment: I've added Log in last catch block...where Exception e showing that exception

Comment: Okay, but post your full logcat of the error

Answer (score 0):

I had exact same problem in past. I had the problem with wrong parametres.After spending some time now I was able to solve my problem.Posting my answer for others. Passing wrong email and password to the service was right and server was consuming those parameters as well and because there was an error(because email and password) that is why it was returning 500 code. So, I checked for status code if it was 200 then I used getInputStream() method and else i called getErrorStream() method. By this way i got the stream that has property for error(this property contains error detail). Below is the code i used

```
if (conn.getResponseCode() != HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getErrorStream()));
    } else {
        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
    }
```

The main idea behind that was to check response code first. If that is HTTP_OK as mentioned in the code it means that is fine if not then go for error stream to check what is the error is received from server. Hope that helps.

Comment: before reading stream use my mentioned code if status is ok then get streams else get error stream for further query

Answer (score 0):

Your url maybe some issue, you can encode then retry.

You can try:

```
protected static final String ALLOWED_URI_CHARS = "@#&=*+-_.,:!?()/~'%";
String encodedUrl = Uri.encode(url, ALLOWED_URI_CHARS);
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(encodedUrl).openConnection();
```